How to spawn an actor as child of another actor such that its location, rotation is relative to its parent, in blueprints?
I am relatively new to the Unreal engine but have experience in making games in Unity. Basically, I want to make a first-person item-pickup system.
In Unity, I would raycast a sphere (sphere trace in Unreal engine) check for collided objects, and check if any object had an interactable interface. Then spawn the object as a child of a gameobject that is inside the camera (i.e. camera is the parent of the gameobject).
In Unreal Engine, I did all of the above but when the child is spawned it doesn't stay at the location assigned to it relative to the camera.

What is currently happening:





Blueprints:

BPI_GroundInteractable:
Interface used for objects that are pickable


BP_MasterGroundInteractable
Base blueprint for interactable items, currently contains a sphere for testing and is the only pickable item




BP_FirstPersonCharacter
First-person character provided in the template, I have removed the first-person arms. Add sprint and head bob which are working correctly.

Interact method:




I found out that you can use sockets, but since I am NOT using a mesh I don't think I can use sockets. In some tutorials, the tutor was using a static mesh with no 'mesh' assigned as the child of the first-person camera. And then he would replace the static mesh 'mesh' with the mesh of the picked-up item. This is not an option for me because I want the player to be able to pick up guns, torches rocks, etc.


I discovered that when set simulate physics is enabled the object doesn't changes its position relative to its parent or parent component. I used a blank scene component and used AttachActorToComponent node to attack the spawned sphere to the component. If set simulate physics is enabled in the beginning (weather using event BeginPlay or from actor details panel) the sphere doesn't follow. I also tried SetSimulatePhysics and SetActorEnableCollision node to don't allow physics after pickup but that also didn't work.
